# Spring data JPA - specification

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-repositories

I'm facing issues when passing specification to the `repository.findAll()`

```
Version:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.2.4.RELEASE
```

Repository

```
@Repository
public interface ServerAttributesRepository extends JpaRepository<ServerAttributes, Integer>{
    public ServerAttributes findById(int Id);
}
```

and when I call `repository.findAll` by passing specification, I get error

```
ServerAttributeSpecification spec1 = new ServerAttributeSpecification(
            new SearchCriteria("server", SearchOperation.EQUALITY, "1"));
    List<ServerAttributes> serverAttributesList = serverAttributesRepository.findAll(spec1);
```

**Error:**

```
Cannot resolve method 'findAll(com.cloud.compareService.specification.ServerAttributeSpecification)'
```

and I can not find `findAll(Specification<T> spec)` in my JpaRepository

[image]

reference: https://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-query-search-language-more-operations

Comment: Please don't include screenshots of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extend `JpaSpecificationExecutor` interface to get support for Specifications, so try:

```java
@Repository
public interface ServerAttributesRepository extends JpaRepository<ServerAttributes, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<ServerAttributes> {
    public ServerAttributes findById(int Id);
}
```